# C code - arrays. Unsure how to update arrays from 0 to 1 with users choices

Tags: arrays, c

[edit] I was able to figure out one of my initial problems. it turns out that it was an issue with my if statements. I needed to add a few else if in there and change the 5 and 10's to 6 and 11's.

If anyone has any INFORMATION on how to help me with the array portion -  how to print my 'seating chart' showing open seats as 0 and have them change to 1 everytime a seat is taken, i'd appreciate it.

> 

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
    /*write a program to assign seats on each flight of the airline's only plane
     (capacity 10 seats).
     Display the following menu:

            Please type 1 for "first class"
            Please type 2 for "economy"

     \*1 = first class (seats 1-5).
     \*2 = economy (seats 6-10).

      Print a boarding pass indicating seat number and class.

     \* Use a one-dimensional array to represent seating chart.
     \*initialize all the elements of the array to 0 to indicate open_seat, 1 = taken_seat

     Never assign a seat that has already been assigned.

     When one section is full, ask person if other class is acceptable.
     \*yes, make appropriate seat assignment.
     *no, print message "Next flight leaves in 3 hours."*/

    bool taken_seats [10] = {0};
    int first_class = 1;
    int economy_class = 6;
    int class_choice;
    int backup_class_choice;

    do
    {
        printf("\n\nPlease type 1 for 'First Class'\n"
               "Please type 2 for 'Economy'\n"
               "Please type 5 to exit the menu\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &class_choice);

        //FIRST CLASS
        if(class_choice == 1 && first_class < 6)
        {
            taken_seats[first_class] = true;
            printf("First Class ticket.\nSeat: %d", first_class);
            first_class++;
        }//end if

        else if(class_choice == 1 && first_class == 6 && economy_class <11)
        {
            printf("Sorry, all seats are taken. Would you like a seat in Economy?" 
                   "\nType 3 for yes and 4 for no.");
            scanf("%d", &backup_class_choice);
        
           if(backup_class_choice == 3)
           {
               taken_seats[economy_class] = true;
               printf("Economy Class ticket.\nSeat: ");
               printf("%d\n", economy_class);
               economy_class++;
           }//end if

           else if(backup_class_choice == 4)
           {
               printf("The next plane leaves in 3 hours." 
                      " We apologize for any inconvenience."
                      "\nGoodbye.\n");
              class_choice = 5; 
           }//end inner else if
        }//end outer else if
        else if(class_choice == 1 && first_class == 6 && economy_class == 11)
        {
            printf("There are no more seats available. "
                    "The next flight leaves in 3 hours." 
                    " We apologize for any inconvenience\n");
            class_choice = 5;
        } //end else if


        //ECONOMY
        if(class_choice == 2 && economy_class < 11)
        {
            taken_seats[economy_class] = true;
            printf("Economy Class ticket.\nSeat: ");
            printf("%d\n", economy_class);
            economy_class++;
        }//end if

        else if(class_choice == 2 && economy_class == 11 && first_class < 6)
        {
            printf("Sorry, all seats are taken."
                   " Would you like a seat in First Class?"
                   "\nType 3 for yes and 4 for no.\n");
            scanf("%d", &backup_class_choice);
            
            if(backup_class_choice == 3)
            {
               taken_seats[first_class] = true;
               printf("First Class ticket.\nSeat: ");
               printf("%d", first_class);
               first_class++;
             }//end if

           else if(backup_class_choice == 4)
           {
             printf("The next plane leaves in 3 hours. "
                    "We apologize for any inconveniences." 
                    " Goodbye.\n");
           }//end inner else if
        }//end outer else if

        else if(class_choice == 2 && economy_class == 11 && first_class == 6)
        {
            printf("There are no more economy seats available."
                   " The next flight leaves in 3 hours."
                   " We apologize for any inconvenience\n");
            class_choice = 5;
        }//end else if
       
        

    }//end do
    while(class_choice != 5);

    return 0;
}//end main
```

Comment: Please [edit] and remove the line numbers. and the `\<` etc. We need code that can be copy/pasted/compiled. Yolu also need to tell us what's wrong.

Comment: *"I was able to figure out my initial problem. [...] If anyone has any tips on the array portion"*, if you have a new question, please ask a new question. Stack Overflow is not a forum, it is a question-answer site with quite strict format. Also this site is not really for "tips", but once you have _working_ code and you want feedback on it, you can try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have working code as it runs. Just asking on another section of the same problem. I had already asked on arrays prior, but I updated to show that I figured everything else out and just needed help on that final bit. and by tips I mean help. Which is what I though the site was for? my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending upon which C compiler you were using, you should have received a warning about statements having no effect.

```
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Reservations/main.c|99|warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]|
```

That would refer to one of the following statements in your code.

```
taken_seats[economy_class];
```

That statement is essentially doing nothing.

With that in mind, I did a few revisions and cleanup to your code and changed those lines of code to assign a Boolean value to them, which is probably what is supposed to happen.  Following is a revised version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
    /*write a program to assign seats on each flight of the airline's only plane
     (capacity 10 seats).
     Display the following menu:

            Please type 1 for "first class"
            Please type 2 for "economy"

     \*1 = first class (seats 1-5).
     \*2 = economy (seats 6-10).

      Print a boarding pass indicating seat number and class.

     \* Use a one-dimensional array to represent seating chart.
     \*initialize all the elements of the array to 0 to indicate open_seat, 1 = taken_seat

     Never assign a seat that has already been assigned.

     When one section is full, ask person if other class is acceptable.
     \*yes, make appropriate seat assignment.
     *no, print message "Next flight leaves in 3 hours."*/

    bool taken_seats [10] = {0};
    int first_class = 2;
    int economy_class = 6;
    int class_choice;
    int backup_class_choice;

    do
    {
        printf("\n\nPlease type 1 for 'First Class'\nPlease type 2 for 'Economy'\nPlease type 3 to exit the menu\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &class_choice);

        //FIRST CLASS
        if(class_choice == 1 && first_class < 6)
        {
            taken_seats[first_class] = true;   /* Perform update of the seat */
            printf("First Class ticket.\nSeat: %d", first_class);
            first_class++;
        }//end if
        if(class_choice == 1 && first_class == 6)
        {
            printf("Sorry, all seats are taken.");
        }//end if

        if(class_choice == 1 && first_class == 6 && economy_class == 11)
        {
            printf("1There are no more seats available.  The next flight leaves in 3 hours.  We apologize for any inconvenience\n");
        } //end if


        if(class_choice == 1 && first_class == 6 && economy_class < 10)
        {
            printf("Would you like a seat in Economy? Type 1 for yes and 2 for no.");
            scanf("%d", &backup_class_choice);
        }//end if
        if(backup_class_choice == 1)
        {
            taken_seats[economy_class] = true;
            printf("Economy Class ticket.\nSeat: ");
            printf("%d\n", economy_class);
            economy_class++;
        }//end if
        if(backup_class_choice == 2)
        {
            printf("The next plane leaves in 3 hours. We apologize for any inconvenience.  Goodbye.\n");
        }//end if


        //ECONOMY
        if(class_choice == 2 && economy_class < 10)
        {
            taken_seats[economy_class] = true;
            printf("Economy Class ticket.\nSeat: ");
            printf("%d\n", economy_class);
            economy_class++;
        }//end if
        if(class_choice == 2 && economy_class == 10)
        {
            printf("Sorry, all seats are taken.");
        }//end if
        if(class_choice == 2 && economy_class == 10 && first_class == 5)
        {
            printf("There are no more economy seats available.  The next flight leaves in 3 hours.  We apologize for any inconvenience\n");
        }//end if


        if(class_choice == 2 && economy_class == 10 && first_class < 5)
        {
            printf("Would you like a seat in First Class? Type 1 for yes and 2 for no.");
            scanf("%d", &backup_class_choice);
        }//end if
        if(backup_class_choice == 1)
        {
            taken_seats[first_class] = true;
            printf("First Class ticket.\nSeat: ");
            printf("%d", first_class);
            first_class++;
        }//end if

        if(backup_class_choice == 2)
        {
            printf("The next plane leaves in 3 hours. We apologize for any inconveniences. Goodbye.\n");
        }//end if

    }//end do
    while(class_choice != 3);

    return 0;
}//end main
```

It looks like there is more refinement to be done to this code, such as possibly printing out the seat assignment array, but this should move you along.

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.